# Rails 4: One-to-one controller issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm building an app which consists on sharing résumés. I am using Devise gem. Each user is able to create only one résumé. I made the models and and their relations.  `Resume` `belongs_to` `User` and `User` `has_one` 'Resume'.

After making the views, I wanted to test my app but I got the error: `undefined method`build' for nil:NilClass`

Here is my `ResumeController` and my `routes.rb`

```
class ResumeController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_resume, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:show]

    def show
        # @resume = Resume.find_by(params[:id])
    end

    def new
        @resume = current_user.resume.build
    end

    def create
        @resume = current_user.resume.build(resume_params)

        if @resume.save
            redirect_to @resume, notice: "resume was successfully created"
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def edit
    end

    def update
        if @resume.update(pin_params)
            redirect_to @resume, notice: "resume was successfully updated"
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end


    def destroy
        @resume.destroy
        redirect_to root_path
    end

    private

    def resume_params
        params.require(:resume).permit(:title, :description)
    end

    def find_resume
        @resume = resume.find(params[:id])
    end

end
```

**Routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users 
  resources :resume, except: [:index]
  get 'static_pages/index' 
  root to: "static_pages#index"
end
```

I just want the user to be able to create only one Resume and then he will be able to share it.

**Update:** After following messanjah's answer there was another error coming from the _form.html.erb: `undefined method resumes_path' for #<#<Class:0x00...>.` Here is the gist with forms and model: goo.gl/XvW2LH So you can see all the files closely.

Comment: Please add a little more detail. The backtrace when you get `undefined methodbuild' for nil:NilClass`` would help.

Comment: Done, I just shared a Gist so you can see them all

Answer (score 2):

Without more knowledge of where the error is happening, I can only suggest some areas that might be suspect.

To build a `has_one` relationship, you must use the `build_*association*` constructor.

```
def new
  @resume = current_user.build_resume
end

def create
  @resume = current_user.build_resume(resume_params)
end
```

Comment: I worked, but i still having one message error coming from the _form.html.erb: `undefined method resumes_path' for #<#<Class:0x00...>`. Here is the gist with forms and model: http://goo.gl/XvW2LH It's my first time doing one-to-one modeling.

Comment: It might be easier if you opened a new question for your new issue. And if you add the output of `bundle exec rake routes`, that'll help.